# where does back event is handel in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to refresh the whole page controller on back press. 
I am navigating the viewcontroller using code.

My Code

```
let GTC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoToCart")as! GoToCart
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(GTC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `viewWillAppear` to reload your UI. As you use `navigationController?.pushViewController`, the view will be retained and stored in stack.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Reload the UI           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[viewWillAppear(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear)

`viewWillAppear` is called the first time the view is displayed as well as when the view is displayed again, so it can be called multiple times during the life of the view controller object. It’s called when the view is about to appear as a result of the user tapping the back button, when the view controller’s tab is selected in a tab bar controller etc. Make sure to call `super.viewWillAppear()` at some point in the implementation. You can refresh your UI in this method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Reload the UI           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use protocol

1. Create protocol from where you want to pop back(GoToCart)
2. Create delegate variable in GoToCart
3. Extend GoToCart protocol in MainViewController
4. Give reference to GoToCart of MainViewController when
   navigate
5. Define delegate Method in MainViewController
6. Then you can call delegate method from GoToCart

Example

In GoToCart: Write code below..

```
protocol GoCartControllerDelegate
{
 func childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
}

class GoToCart:UIViewController
{
var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?
....
}
```

Then in mainViewController implement the protocol function end extend to the protocol

```
class MainViewController:UIViewController,GoCartControllerDelegate
{
// Define Delegate Method
func childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
{

 //...here update what you want to update according to the  situation

}
}
```

2 Important thing

when navigating to the gocart controller  code like this

```
let GTC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GoToCart")as! GoToCart
GTC.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(GTC, animated: true)
```

and when popping from gocartViewController 
code like this

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
self.delegate?.childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
```